# Expose aditional APIs via Go Geth Ethereum Client

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, golang

I am asking more experienced Go Geth developers what is the module that is in charge of exposing variables on the Geth Console / RPC.

What I need is to expose the variable containing the addresses in the module `Eth.TxPool` named `Locals`.

In other words I would like to be able to add a local address at runtime, without using the `config.toml` file under this config and restart the node each time:

```
[Eth.TxPool]
Locals = ["0xaddr1","0xaddr2","0xaddr3"]
```

What is the `.go` file in charge of exposing the txpool in the console?

Thank you

EDIT: I started looking around the go-ethereum source code and figured out that the RCP structure is based on "Services" that expose via Interfaces, methods that can be used and interacted with via (HTTP/IPC/WSS), I am now trying to figure out how to create/extend a service with my own methods.
I found useful these files: `rpc/rpc.go`, `rpc/doc.go`